# How to get a selected list item using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, selectlistitem

I display a list of contents from my database in my application. I fetch the records from the database and iterate through the for-each loop in the front end and it displays the contents. When I try to click any of the items it only shows the first item in the list. Below is my code. How can I overcome this issue?

```
function userselection()
        {
            var selecteduser1=document.getElementById("lbl_user").innerHTML;
            document.writeln(selecteduser1);
        }

<div style="border: 2px solid activeborder;width:300px;height: 400px;border-radius: 5px;">
                    <ul id="userlist" style="text-align: left;">
                        <c:forEach items="${list_onlineusers}" var="userslist">
                            <li  id="li_user" style="list-style-image: url(images/online.png);cursor: pointer;height: 25px;margin-left: 0;margin-right: 10%;margin-top: 0.5em;margin-bottom: 7%;" value="${userslist}">
                                <label onmousedown="userselection()" id="lbl_user" style="font-family:Trebuchet MS,Times,serif;color: black;font-size: 16px;cursor: pointer;">
                                    ${userslist}
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: So instead do you want to select all the items?

Comment: @Sn. no i want to select a single item and continue with my functions with that selected data

Comment: You are using same id, instead you can have "lbl_user${index}"

Answer (score 1):

**Definition and Usage of ID**

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).The id attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet, and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with the specific id.

You're using the same id for all the items in the list. You have to change the `<c:forEach>` loop little to add the loop count to the id. so, that each item will have an unique id. Please change your code like below

```
<c:forEach items="${list_onlineusers}" var="userslist" varStatus="count">
   <li  id="li_user${count.index}" value="${userslist}">
        <label onmousedown="userselection()" id="lbl_user${count.index}">
          ${userslist}
         </label>
   </li>
</c:forEach>
```

The above change will set an unique id for each item. Now you can pass the unique id of the item clicked on registering an eventlistener to the document and do whatever you want. First of all, you need to ensure that there is unique id for every element in the document.

Note : I have removed the inline CSS style properties from your HTML to improve readablity

Comment: i have made these changes to my code what to do with function?

Comment: you have to pass the element or id of the element which triggered mousedown like `userselection(this)` or `userselection(this.id)` and implement the function whatever you want!

Comment: actually i mentioned my function code above in that i have used innerHTML instead of that is there any other attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ID 'lbl_user' for all selections; since all the items are sharing the same ID, when

```
var selecteduser1=document.getElementById("lbl_user").innerHTML;
```

is called, it only grabs the first available ID. Try to assign a unique ID to each item instead.

Or, in the function, simply do:

```
function userselection(){
     var selecteduser1=this.innerHTML;
     document.writeln(selecteduser1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You looping is wrong done as your loop will create multiples ids of id="li_user" & id="lbl_user" on the view which will not be unique. Fixed that first.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can try without using Java script.

```
  List<String> list = (List<String>) s;
 {
    %>
<tr>
<td>MobileCode</td>
<td>Company</td>
<td>Camera</td>

<%
for (String p : list) {
%>
<tr>
<td><%=p.getMn()%></td>
<td><%=p.getCmnm()%></td>
<td><%=p.getCmr()%></td>

<td><a href="xyz`enter code here.jsp?mn=<%=p.getMn()%>"
onClick="return confirm('Are you sure for Delete')">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<%
}
}
}
enter code here

}
%>
</table>
```

Like this.

Comment: `Scriptlets` shouldn't be used anymore. Use `JSTL` tags and `EL` instead.